# ISDEV : fatal error -1027: Failed signing .dll

Tags: installshield-2016

I know the answer to this question (which I'll post below the question). When I googled this error message **nothing** came up so I thought this might help someone else in the future. Here's the original problem:

I just switched build platforms (from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017) and now I can't Build - I get the error above. I started getting it for a different .dll so I deleted that .dll and now I get it for this one. It seems that no matter which .dll it encounters it gets this error.

So we use TFS do do the builds, but even if I just go to the command line with the same source and run iscmdbld I get the same error. Strangely if I do the same for the code pulled from a TFS2013 build it works fine. Also running signtool.exe works in the folder.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough, but when I googled "Fatal error -1027" nothing came up.

The problem was in the source mapping. I wasn't getting the cert to the correct place. And when I tried signing it from the command-line I was copying the cert into the build folder so that I didn't have to type out a long path.

Comment: From the setup project, I had to go to 6 > Prepare For Release > Releases, then in the main screen  Builds > Express > SingleImage, signing tab. Digital Certificate Information had an invalid path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, slightly different cause. My signing certificate expired and it was renewed, password changed... but I forgot to change it in >>Media>>Releases>>Image>>Signing